# Can a JSON file's outermost thing be an array instead of an object?

Tags: arrays, json

Is it okay if my JSON file contains the following?

```
[
{ldraw="003238a",lgeo="003238a",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238b",lgeo="003238b",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238c",lgeo="003238c",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238d",lgeo="003238d",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0}
]
```

Is it okay just to create an array, or does the outermost thing need to be an object? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [RFC 7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt),

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>   the following three literal names:
>
> ```
>   false null true
> ```
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are
>   allowed.

Also, replace '=' with ':' , enclose property names with "". You can also use an online lint tool to validate the same

```
[
    {
        "ldraw": "003238a",
        "lgeo": "003238a",
        "slope": 0,
        "anton": 0,
        "lutz": 0,
        "owen": 0,
        "damien": 0
    },
    {
        "ldraw": "003238b",
        "lgeo": "003238b",
        "slope": 0,
        "anton": 0,
        "lutz": 0,
        "owen": 0,
        "damien": 0
    },
    {
        "ldraw": "003238c",
        "lgeo": "003238c",
        "slope": 0,
        "anton": 0,
        "lutz": 0,
        "owen": 0,
        "damien": 0
    },
    {
        "ldraw": "003238d",
        "lgeo": "003238d",
        "slope": 0,
        "anton": 0,
        "lutz": 0,
        "owen": 0,
        "damien": 0
    }
]
```